# How can I use a postactivate script using Python 3 venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I'm using `venv` (used `pyvenv` to create the environment) and would like to set up environment variables here, but `postactivate` looks like a `virtualenv` thing. Can this be done with `venv`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`venv` has the `activate` script which you can modify to add your environment variables.

I would add the variables at the bottom, making a nice comment block to clearly separate the core functionality and my custom variables.

Comment: any idea about the global postdeactivate?

Answer (score 2):

Open `[your_virtualenv_dir]/bin/activate` (not activate.csh or activate.fish)

To set environment variable on activate, put your exports at the bottom of the file e.g.

```
export SOME_VARIABLE=some_value
```

To unset the environment variable upon deactivation, unset the variables within the deactivate function at the top of the file e.g.

```
deactivate(
  ...
  # default code by venv
  ...
  
  unset SOME_VARIABLE

)
```

Seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Put your setup config in `[your_virtualenv_dir]/bin/postactivate` and your teardown config in `[your_virtualenv_dir]/bin/predeactivate`.

e.g. in `postactivate`:

```
YOUR_ENV_VAR="hello world!"
```

e.g. in `predeactivate`:

```
unset YOUR_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: This doesn't work with stdlib venv.