# Python script kicked off from batch file can't see env vars set in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, environment-variables, subprocess, python-os

I am using a `.bat` file to:

1. Set environment variables
2. Kick off a Python program (that uses these environment variables)

```
@ECHO OFF
REM TODO: figure out why Python can't see this
SET MY_ENV_VAR="foo"

CALL C:\code\repo\venv\Scripts\activate
CD /d C:\code\repo
@ECHO ON
REM kick off Python, where os.getenv can't see MY_ENV_VAR
CMD /k run_python_console_script
```

If you're curious, the `run_python_console_script` kicks off a command made via an [Entry Point](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points).

When I run `os.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR")` it doesn't return `"foo"`, it returns `None`.  Why is this?

I don't want to use `SETX` ([docs](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)), I want the environment variable scoped to just this batch script.

---

**Other Answers**

[How to access Batch Script variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55358878/) and [Python Subprocess Does not Get Environment Variable from Bat File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54608082/) want to invoke a `.bat` script as a subprocess.  I don't want to do this, the `.bat` script is my parent process.

`virtualenvwrapper` supports a `postactivate` script (see
[How can I use a postactivate script using Python 3 venv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39056356/11163122) and [Set specific environment variables activating a Python virtual environment](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2020/10/16/set-specific-environment-variables-activating-python-virtual-environment/)) but I am not using `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the venv?  I don't have a lot of experience with venvs, but I can imagine that activating the venv would leave you with a fresh environment.

Comment: Please read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It makes a big difference if the environment variable `MY_ENV_VAR` is defined with `SET MY_ENV_VAR="foo"` (not recommended) or with `SET "MY_ENV_VAR=foo"` (recommended, but requires enabled command extensions which are enabled by default). So my first suggestion is using in the batch file below `@ECHO OFF` the command line `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to defined the required execution environment completely.

Comment: My second suggestion is changing `SET MY_ENV_VAR="foo"` to `SET "MY_ENV_VAR=foo"`, run the batch file and check if the Python script using [os.environ\["MY_ENV_VAR"\]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) returns now the string `foo` or __null__ or using [os.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR",default="undefined")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) and check if that returns the string `foo` or the string `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @Mofi for many possible things to try in the comments section!

The gotcha was in first comment linking to here (placement of `""` around the environment variable): https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/11163122

```
REM TODO: figure out why Python can't see this
SET MY_ENV_VAR="foo"

REM DONE: this works (quotes on outside)
SET "MY_ENV_VAR=foo"
```

It seems the `venv` activation was not clobbering preexisting environment variables, as @JohnGordon speculated in the comments.

When `pip install`ed on Windows, the `run_python_console_script` [Entry Point](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) is installed into the `venv` as `venv\Scripts\run_python_console_script.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Changes made using the SET command are NOT permanent, they apply to the current CMD prompt only and remain only until the CMD window is closed.

To permanently change a variable at the command line use SetX

Comment: Not relevant, sorry. A process started BY this process should inherit this process's environment. Certainly does with a Delphi executable designed to show a user-set variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sadly, `SETX` would cause an environment variable collision for me; I had called out in the question description that I am not interested in `SETX`.

Comment: This is answer indeed not relevant here because of the environment variable is defined in the memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which is copied by [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) into the memory of `cmd.exe` started at end of the batch file and copied once again by `CreateProcess` into the memory of `python.exe` started by second `cmd.exe`.

Comment: So the environment variable must not be defined persistent stored for current user or local machine using `setx` which does not modify the environment of currently running `cmd.exe` process and therefore does not define the environment variable for second `cmd.exe` and for `python.exe` started next. I recommend to read chapters B) and F) in my answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) F) explains step by step with an example the environment variable management.